# run script every n minutes without editing crontab file manually

Tags: linux

Is there a command that can edit crontab ? 
( I don't want to edit it manually )

For example :

```
command -parameter * * * * * script
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command `crontab  file` will set the crontab to the contents of the given `file` - if the lines in it are properly formatted (otherwise it will just give an error).

You can use `-` instead of a filename to read from the standard input, e.g.:

```
echo "* * * * * script" | crontab -
```